# Android apk expansion without .zip files

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to implement the sample project that google provided for apk expansioning. There is an external library for zip files but I only required the simple one without the compressing. But the sample project without zip has an implementation like:

- Check if file exist
- If file exist, validate the file
- If not, download the file and validate

Both validate methods uncompress the zip file and validate it. And they use a class called "ZipResourceFile" which I don't have in my java or android packages. I don't even understand why they put a zip validator method in a library without zip support. Is there such a way to require this validator with non-zipped files or do I have to write my own?

Used documentation: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html (which is clearly unsufficiant, they keep mapping to the sample they provided which is completely different)

Used sample code: The sample code in the sdk manager -> extras -> Google play Expansion Library + Google play licensing library

Not to mention you need to build your own dependency with the old way by creating the licensing library and import it to expansion library and then importing it to your project. There is no gradle support nor a whole jar.

Edit: I forgot to mention that ZipResourceFile.java class is in the zip_file project that google provided which is not in the project-properties of downloader_library project which uses the ZipResourceFile...

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something?  APKs are zip files, so to validate them your project will need some zip support.

Comment: Expansions are the big files to exceed your 50mb limit on play store. Like media files, high res images or pdfs etc. that you put in your assets.

Comment: And in the documentation, they clearly pointed out that you need the zip library if you need a zip support.